# Ionic 2, this.nav.push() is undefined

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I come from Ionic 1 and I'm starting with ionic 2.
I get an error when I use this.nav.push(nameOftheOterPage) right after a promise but this function this.nav.push is totally working when I use it outside the promise function authHandler:

```
    import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
    import {ItemDetailsPage} from '../item-details/item-details';

    @Page({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
    })
    export class LoginPage {
      static get parameters() {
        return [[NavController]];
      }

      constructor(nav) {
        this.nav = nav;
        this.firebaseUrl = "https://MYFIREBASE.firebaseio.com";
        this.authType = "login";
        this.error_username = false;
      }

      login(form) {
      if(form.controls.username.value === null){

        this.error_username = true;
      }
      else{
          /* Authenticate User */ 
          var ref = new Firebase(this.firebaseUrl);
          ref.authWithPassword({
            email    : form.controls.username.value,
            password : form.controls.password.value
          }, this.authHandler);
          }
        }

      authHandler(error, authData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        } else {
            console.log(authData);
            this.nav.push(ItemDetailsPage);
        }
      }
    }
```

Could you help me with it?

Thanks.

Comment: What's undefined? `nav` or `push`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `this` is a little tricky in javascript objects, especially when callbacks are involved. (I recommend this [interesting article](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/) about it).

The gist of it, is that you always need to keep track of which object was the one that called the function, because `this` will be bound to the calling object.

The solution for your problem will be to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method) your class' `this` to the callback, so that `this` will be what you think it should be. So when you call `authWithPassword`, do it like this:

```
ref.authWithPassword({
   email: form.controls.username.value,
   password: form.controls.password.value
}, this.authHandler.bind(this));
```

**Edit**
As @Manu Valdés suggested in the comments, another option you have, if you want to avoid the use of `bind`, is to define `authHandler` in the following way:

```
authHandler = (error, authData) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    } else {
        console.log(authData);
        this.nav.push(ItemDetailsPage);
    }
}
```

This works because in [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions), their `this` is set to that of the outer execution context, no matter who the caller was.

Comment: @yarons for discussion's sake, how would you accomplish this using arrow syntax ( => ) which should make `this` refer to the scope where the function is implemented rather than where it is executed?

Comment: @ManuValdés instead of using `bind`, you can define the callback `authHandler` like this: `authHandler = (error, authData) => {...`. This will also work.

Comment: @yarons I think I like this approach better, not having to explicitly handle `this` context

Comment: Both way are valid. I guess it's a matter of style. But I'll edit this into the answer

Comment: Hi, how to mark this question as answer ? Thanks to everybody who helped me to answer this question.

Comment: Do you see the gray "V" under the score of the answer, on the left? That's a button